# Overflow is messing up with scrollY value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I have been trying to read the value of scrollY in my reactapp. But I found that it is being messed by overflow.

Here is the code that I used to read the scrollY:

```
    import React from "react";

import{useEffect, useState} from "react"


 
export default function Test() {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const setScroll = () => {
    setOffset(window.scrollY);
  };

    useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", setScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      
      
      <div style={{color:"red"}}>{offset}</div>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my app.jsx >>>

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { FetchData } from './components/FetchData';
import { Counter } from './components/Counter';

import abc2 from './img/abc2.jpg'
import './custom.css'
import Resume from './components/resumePage/Resume';
import Test from './components/Test.jsx';


var backGStyle={
  backgroundImage:`url(${abc2})`,
  minHeight: "100vh",
  backgroundSize:'cover',
  color:'red'
}

export default class App extends Component {
  static displayName = App.name;

  render () {
    return (
      
      <div className="app" style={backGStyle}>
        <div className="mask">
      <Layout> 
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
        <Route path='/resume' component={Resume} />
        <Route path='/test' component={Test} />
      </Layout>
      </div>
      </div>
     
    );
  }
}
```

and my custom.css >>

```
a {
  color: #0366d6;
}

code {
  color: #E01A76;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b6ec2;
  border-color: #1861ac;
}

.backgroundBody{
  position: relative;
 
}


.app .mask{
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    overflow:auto;
    
}

.abc{
  color: aqua;
}
```

And if I remove the overflow: auto from custome.css .app .mask, I am being able to get the value of scrollY but my background image will be messed up, there will be white space in the background of half of the content like this >>>>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try element.scrollTop since your using divs as masks. ScrollY is only for the scroll position of the window (HTML element). Your question is a little vague, if your trying to align you background images use background-position and background-size. also set your overflow to clip.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: Hi, using the step I am still geting half of the content from my home page, I cant scroll down ( using overflow: clip). Also assigning height, background position and size also deosnot help.

Comment: Is it possible you have an unclosed syntax error? I'm not familiar with react (or any js framework/library) but i copy and pasted your source code into jsfiddle and it popped up with a syntax error; and uh, i guess i also failed to mention, set background repeat to no repeat